# Does CudaMallocManaged allocate memory on the device?

Tags: cuda, gpu

I'm using Unified Memory to simplify access to data on the CPU and GPU. As far as I know, cudaMallocManaged should allocate memory on the device. I wrote a simple code to check that:

```
#define TYPE float
#define BDIMX 16
#define BDIMY 16
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
__global__ void kernel(TYPE *g_output, TYPE *g_input, const int dimx, const int dimy)
{
__shared__ float s_data[BDIMY][BDIMX];
  int ix = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  int iy = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
  int in_idx = iy * dimx + ix; // index for reading input
  int tx = threadIdx.x; // thread’s x-index into corresponding shared memory tile  
  int ty = threadIdx.y; // thread’s y-index into corresponding shared memory tile 
  s_data[ty][tx] = g_input[in_idx];
  __syncthreads();
  g_output[in_idx] = s_data[ty][tx] * 1.3;
  }


int main(){
  int size_x = 16, size_y = 16;
  dim3 numTB;
    numTB.x = (int)ceil((double)(size_x)/(double)BDIMX) ;
    numTB.y = (int)ceil((double)(size_y)/(double)BDIMY) ;
  dim3 tbSize; 
  tbSize.x = BDIMX;
  tbSize.y = BDIMY;
  float* a,* a_out;
  cudaMallocManaged((void**)&a,     size_x * size_y * sizeof(TYPE));
  cudaMallocManaged((void**)&a_out, size_x * size_y * sizeof(TYPE));

  kernel <<<numTB, tbSize>>>(a_out, a, size_x, size_y);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
  return 0;
}
```

So I'm not even accessing the data on the CPU to avoid any page faults so the memory should supposedly be on the device memory. However when I run nvprof on this code, I get the following results:

```
  invocations                               Metric Name                        Metric Description         Min         Max         Avg
Device "Tesla K40c (0)"
Kernel: kernel(float*, float*, int, int)
        1                   local_load_transactions                   Local Load Transactions           0           0           0
        1                  local_store_transactions                  Local Store Transactions           0           0           0
        1                  shared_load_transactions                  Shared Load Transactions           8           8           8
        1                 shared_store_transactions                 Shared Store Transactions           8           8           8
        1                          gld_transactions                  Global Load Transactions           8           8           8
        1                          gst_transactions                 Global Store Transactions           8           8           8
        1                  sysmem_read_transactions           System Memory Read Transactions          32          32          32
        1                 sysmem_write_transactions          System Memory Write Transactions          34          34          34
        1                    tex_cache_transactions                Texture Cache Transactions           0           0           0
        1                    dram_read_transactions           Device Memory Read Transactions           0           0           0
        1                   dram_write_transactions          Device Memory Write Transactions           0           0           0
```

So apparently the array is allocated on system memory and not the device memory. What am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have multiple GPUs in your system? UM behaves differently when there are multiple GPUs in the system which are not P2P capable. If that is the case try profiling your code with CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="0"

Comment: You should provide some basic info about your hardware and environment ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Managed memory really does allocate physical memory on the GPU. You can confirm yourself this is the case by doing something like the following to your code:

```
#include <iostream>

void report_gpu_mem()
{
    size_t free, total;
    cudaMemGetInfo(&free, &total);
    std::cout << "Free = " << free << " Total = " << total <<std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    float* a,* a_out;
    size_t sz = 1 << 24; // 16Mb
    report_gpu_mem();
    cudaMallocManaged((void**)&a, sz);
    report_gpu_mem();
    cudaMallocManaged((void**)&a_out, sz);
    report_gpu_mem();
    cudaFree(a);
    report_gpu_mem();
    cudaFree(a_out);
    report_gpu_mem();
    return cudaDeviceReset();
}
```

Which is now allocating 16Mb for each of two managed allocations, and then freeing them. No host or device access occurs, so there should be no triggered transfers or synchronisation. The size is large enough that it should exceed the minimum granularity of the GPU memory manager and trigger changes in visible free memory. Compiling and running it does this:

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_52 sleepy.cu 
$ CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES="0" ./a.out 
Free = 4211929088 Total = 4294770688
Free = 4194869248 Total = 4294770688
Free = 4178092032 Total = 4294770688
Free = 4194869248 Total = 4294770688
Free = 4211654656 Total = 4294770688
```

The physical free memory on the GPU is clearly being incremented and decremented by 16Mb at each alloc/free.