# Does cudaMallocManaged immediately allocate memory on all devices?

Tags: memory-management, cuda, dynamic-memory-allocation

A followup question to:

[Does CudaMallocManaged allocate memory on the device?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36778089/1593077)

about `cudaMallocManaged()` on a system with several GPUs.  When we invoke `cudaMallocManaged()`, does it allocate global device memory...

- on *all* GPUs on a system immediately when called, or
- on the current device only, and allocate memory on other devices when they first access the region?
- in some other, possibly more complex, pattern?

(and let's ignore the initial visibility flag)

(I would check but I don't currently have access to a machine with multiple GPUs)

Comment: https://devblogs.nvidia.com/parallelforall/unified-memory-cuda-beginners/